# Dynamic document.ready ids on jsp page

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

I have a jsp webpage which is dynamically generated.  I want to have tooltips on some of the images and the tooltip script I am using requires that each image to have a unique id and the `$(document).ready(function(){});` refer to that image id.  Is this possible?  I can easily generate a unique id for the html img tag but when I try to do the same for the script it gives an error.  I have included my code.

```
<logic:iterate id="results" name="appStatus" scope="session">
    <logic:equal name="results" property="name" value='<%= name%>'> 
        <td>
            <logic:equal value="up" name="results" property="status">
                <img src="img/status_up.png">
            </logic:equal>
            <logic:equal value="down" name="results" property="status">
                <img id="alert" src="img/status_alert.png">
                <div class="tooltip">
                    <bean:write name="results" property="description"/>
                </div>
                <script>
                    $(document).ready(function() {
                        $("#alert").tooltip({ position: 'right top', effect: 'slide'});
                    });
                </script>
            </logic:equal>
            <logic:equal value="other" name="results" property="status">
                <img id="other" src="img/status_info.png">
                <div class="tooltip">
                    <bean:write name="results" property="description"/>
                </div>
                <script>
                    $(document).ready(function() {
                        $("#other").tooltip({ position: 'right top', effect: 'slide'});
                    });
                </script>
            </logic:equal>
        </td>
    </logic:equal>
</logic:iterate>
```

so for this code each img with id "alert" would need to have its own unique id and the document ready script would need to refer to that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give the `<img>` a unique id:

```
<img id="alert<c:out value='${indexNum}' />" src="img/status_alert.png">
```

and likewise in the script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
                        $("#alert<c:out value='${indexNum}' />").tooltip({ position: 'right top', effect: 'slide'});
                    })
```

So the ids will be alert0, alert1, etc. indexNum is the name I've given the iteration number variable, specify the name for it like this:

```
<logic:iterate id="results" name="appStatus" scope="session" indexId="indexNum">
```